# Avoid updating column if set to 1

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO user_list (USER_ID,USERNAME,NAME,ACTIVITY,PRIVATE)
VALUES(?,?,?,1,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE USERNAME=?, NAME=?, ACTIVITY=ACTIVITY+1,PRIVATE=?
```

PRIVATE can be 0 or 1. I need to insert it according to a parameter, but if PRIVATE is already 1 on that row, it shouldn't be set as 0.

Basically if it turns 1, it can never become 0

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: Not clear. If is set to 1 and attempt to insert and set to 0 do you want to reject whole insert or accept changes to all other columns keeping activity as 1?

Comment: All columns can change except PRIVATE. That column can change only from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of the column `PRIVATE`:

```
PRIVATE = PRIVATE OR VALUES(PRIVATE)
```

which will retain the value `1` if this is the original value, or change it to the new value if the original value is `0`:

```
INSERT INTO user_list (USER_ID, USERNAME, NAME, ACTIVITY, PRIVATE)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, 1, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE USERNAME = VALUES(USERNAME), 
                        NAME = VALUES(NAME), 
                        ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY + 1, 
                        PRIVATE = PRIVATE OR VALUES(PRIVATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Why change the value at all?

```
INSERT INTO user_list (USER_ID, USERNAME, NAME, ACTIVITY, PRIVATE) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, 1, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE USERNAME=?, NAME=?, ACTIVITY=ACTIVITY+1;
```

Also, are you aware of `VALUES()`?

```
INSERT INTO user_list (USER_ID, USERNAME, NAME, ACTIVITY, PRIVATE) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, 1, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE USERNAME = VALUES(USERNAME),
                            NAME = VALUES(NAME),
                            ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY + 1;
```

This assigns the value that was passed in to those columns.

Comment: I also need to update PRIVATE. 
So that column can be inserted as 0 or 1. Then if it is 0, I should be able to update it to 1.
Only if PRIVATE is 1, I shouldn't be able to update that column

Comment: @Erry215 . . . Just add `private = 1` to the update list.

Answer (score 0):

Use case to determine if private should remain as is and overwrite with self if so.

```
insert into user_list(id,name,privacy)
values
(1,'aaa','0')
on duplicate key 
update name = values(name)
        ,
         privacy = case when privacy = 0 then values(privacy)
                              when privacy = 1 then privacy
                        end
;
```